# Falling backward at the top of the stairs and correcting the fall

Tags: forces

I was carrying a handful of stuff up the stairs and got off balance and started to fall backwards.  I tried to lean forward and pushed with my quads and corrected the fall in the opposite direction and slammed into the wall at the top of the stairs.   I am curious as to the amount of energy that was generated by the backwards and forwards motions as the force with which I hit the wall was strong. Can someone give me a laypersons explanation of the physics of what happened?